# Redo last foreach loop command on specific condition

Tags: php, web-services, loops, foreach, error-handling

We are making a request to a webservice 1000 times. Each time we make a request we expect a response, but sometimes the webservice fails and provides no response. When this happens we would like to sleep for 30 seconds, and then re-run that loop at the last point it failed. How can this be done?

Here's the basic structure:

```
foreach ( $objects as $object ) {
    foreach ( $otherObjects as $otherObject ) {

        //Prepare request data from $object and $otherObjects

        //Send request to webservice using cURL

        //Receive response and check to see if success
        if ( isset( $response ) ) {
            //Save response to database
        } else {
            //Not successful. Sleep for 30 seconds. Send request again up to 3 times. If ultimately successful continue, if not break and alert system admin.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might break the request off into a function:

```
foreach ( $objects as $object ) {
    foreach ( $otherObjects as $otherObject ) {
        $tries = 0;
        //Receive response and check to see if success.
        while( ($response = doRequest($object, $otherObject)) === false && $tries < 3) {
            //Not successful. Sleep for 30 seconds. Send request again up to 3 times.
            $tries++;
            sleep(30);
        }
        if ( $response ) {
            //Successful save response to database.
        } else {
            //Not successful break and alert system admin.
    }
}

function doRequest($object, $otherObject) {
    //Prepare request data from $object and $otherObject.
    //Send request to webservice using cURL.

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Bonner's answer was good too, but I picked this answer because the logic flowed better and was more intuitive to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ( $objects as $object ) {
    foreach ( $otherObjects as $otherObject ) {

        //Prepare request data from $object and $otherObjects

        //Send request to webservice using cURL

        //Receive response and check to see if success
        if ( isset( $response ) ) {
            //Save response to database
        } else {
            $retriesLeft = 3;
            do {
                sleep(30);

                // perform the request again

                --$retriesLeft;
            }
            while (!isset($response) && $retriesLeft);
        }
    }
}
```

## Update: Simplified Version

```
foreach ( $objects as $object ) {
    foreach ( $otherObjects as $otherObject ) {
        $retriesLeft = 4;

        //Prepare request data from $object and $otherObjects

        do {
            //Send request to webservice using cURL

            //Receive response and check to see if success

            if (isset($response)) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                sleep(30);
                --$retriesLeft;
            }
        }
        while (!isset($response) && $retriesLeft);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I rerun the failed webservice request? Essentially, go back and redo the last loop in memory and continue?

Comment: Just updated to how you how to do this. If you need more information can you provide more on what you are trying to do as there isn't a lot of information we can go on.

Comment: Thx, this helps. Would you simply store the request data in $failedRequests and then at the end of the 1000 requests, loop through $failedRequests and retry?

Comment: I would store the request data under the $retriesLeft variable. Are you wanting it to be at least 30 seconds before the request is retried while carrying on with the other requests?

Comment: Yes wait 30 seconds before retrying, but no need to continue until the failed request is successful.